# OpenAM / OpenDJ custom username field works with less than 4000 users

Tags: ldap, openam, opendj, ldif

I am currently working on a project that uses OpenAM 12.0.2 with OpenDJ 2.6

We had a requirement to make the username editable. So, we ended up creating a custom ldap attribute called `loginId` and updating OpenAM config to use this attribute instead of `uid`.

When I import less than `4000` users, login works fine. When I import `4000+` users login doesn't work for any user, even 1 of the first 4000 users in the directory.

I can manually `ldapsearch` for the users and they exist in the directory, but I can't login with any of them.

We get an "Authorization failed!!" error, which is different to the usual username/password doesn't match error.

If anyone could shed any light on this, I would appreciate it.

Thanks

**Edit**
Here is the attribute definition I am now using.

```
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.37238.2.9 NAME 'loginId' DESC 'username (that can be updated)' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 X-ORIGIN 'project schema')
```

I have rebuilt the indices and still having the same problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is probably because your instance of OpenDJ is configured to reject unindexed search request and you haven't defined and built an index for the loginID attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That was my theory, however I couldn't figure out how to add the index. I am quite new to ldap/ldif

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! For some reason defining the EQUALITY index in the ldif didn't work, but creating the index with dsconfig did the trick!